# Passing function parameter not working?

Tags: javascript, extjs, console.log

I want to pass a parameter to the function, but getting error

> Cannot read property of undefined?"

```
var getNow= function(combo) 
{
var checkValue= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=combo]')[0];
checkValue.isVisible();
};

//call it using this:
getNow("comboBoxName");
```

Comment: Where did you use combo?

Comment: combo is used when i call getNow("comboBoxName")

Comment: Maybe you can create some example code on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var checkValue= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=combo]')[0];
```

change to

```
var checkValue= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=' + combo + ']')[0];
```

Added snippet, it seems work, so you have to give further informations.

```js
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    name: "asd",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    // Template for the dropdown menu.
    // Note the use of the "x-list-plain" and "x-boundlist-item" class,
    // this is required to make the items selectable.
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for=".">',
            '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{abbr} - {name}</li>',
        '</tpl></ul>'
    ),
    // template for the content inside text field
    displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '{abbr} - {name}',
        '</tpl>'
    )
});

var getNow= function(combo) 
{
var checkValue= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=' + combo+ ']')[0];
  
console.log(checkValue.isVisible()); // It returns true or false, then what you want it to do?
};

//call it using this:
getNow("asd");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/ext-all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Unless you use Es6 with special string notation, javascript's string won't parse value for you, so the combo is unused here.

Comment: Created a snippet to see it works, are you just input `"comboBoxName"` to your function? Es6 you can use string like `var  a = 5;  var str = \`this is ${a}. \`; `

Comment: comboBoxName is the "name" of my combo box. But the above did work. thanks